# How do I fix Veracode Security Flaw in C# Windows App

Tags: c#, veracode, hardcode

I performed a Veracode scan on my Windows EXE.
It reported following security vulnerabilities on the code in BOLD below:

certificate = new X509Certificate2......................

**Use of Hard-coded Password (CWE ID 259)(8 flaws)**

```
    string GoogleSecID = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
                                  + Global.AppSettings("GoogleDriveAppIDFileName");
 X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
            try
            {
                string appconfigValue = Global.AppSettings("GoogleAppServiceAccountSecret");
              certificate = new X509Certificate2(GoogleSecID, appconfigValue, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

How do I fix it ?

Thanks,
Gagan